# Perl & MIME::Lite - Why are my .txt attachments blank?

Tags: perl, file, mime, text-files, email-attachments

I've been using [MIME::Lite](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MIME%3a%3aLite) for a short while now and have had no issues until now.

I'm trying to attach a `.txt` file, but the file (after sent) has no content inside of it.

I know the file has something in it because I'm creating the `.txt` file within the same script.  I know where the file is and can see its contents, but when I tell `MIME::Lite` to attach the `.txt` file, the email comes in with just the file name and is only 64 bytes.

Here's the code for the `MIME::Lite` portion of my script:

```
$msg = new MIME::Lite(From => $from,To => $to,Subject => $subject,Data => "Data",Type => "multipart/mixed",); 
$msg->attach(Type => 'TEXT', Data => @message);
$msg->attach(Type => 'TEXT', Path => $stat_file);
$msg->send();
```

Where `$stat_file` = `/in/some/dir/cheese/txt/somefile.txt`

Everything works fine except for the 3rd line.  It is correctly finding & attaching the file that I'm pointing to, but when it hits my email, its a blank `.txt` file of 64 bytes.

I've tried several variations of each of the first 3 lines of this code, but don't know what I'm missing.

Anyone see a reason that this script would perform as explained?

Comment: @cjm - i thought it would be more pertinent to point to the version im using, no?

Comment: no because eventually that version will be removed from CPAN, and the link will break.  It's also not clear that you're actually using that version (it's more likely to just be the latest version at the time you made the link).  If you think the version of the module might be significant, mention it explicitly in the question; don't expect people to look at the URL of your links.

Comment: @cjm - you should write a mini SO API based script to edit the incorrect CPAN links. Double plus points if it's in Perl :)

Comment: @DVK, AFAIK the API is read-only at the moment.  So a script could find the links, but it couldn't fix them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You say you're creating the file pointed to by `$stat_file` in your program, right? Maybe you haven't closed the filehandle to that file, and possibly it's not being flushed out to disk?

Comment: that sounds just about right on.... i gotta find that syntax, but i think you are right

Comment: this is one of those things i'll never forget to do again now haha

Comment: :-) It's bit me before. Now whenever I absolutely know I'm done writing to a file I close it instead of waiting for the filehandle to go out of scope.

Comment: i used to obey the close file law, but got lazy on it because i never saw any detrimental effects of keeping it open... until today, of course